# how to set fields dynamicly in GroupBy in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have below query :

```
  var result = _workOrders.GroupBy(row => row.Asset, (k, g) => new AverageBetweenTwoFailureViewModel
        {
           // fields
        }).ToList();
```

and know I need to set field dynamicly in  `row => row.Asset` dynamicly .
I searched on the `Net`  and I found below codes :

```
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "item");
var body = Expression.Property(arg, "D");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, DateTime>>(body, arg);
var keySelector = lambda.Compile();
```

but that `override` that I used in `Groupby` it's different.

Comment: You can't easily do it in a dynamic way... The "return type" of `GroupBy` (`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`) depends on the type of the `TKey`. So if you select "dynamically" the `TKey`, and the type of the `TKey` can change, then the type of the `result` can change in a dynamic way. The problem isn't unsolvable, but you then will have more and more dynamic code.

Comment: thank you . I'll create method for each field . I just have 4 fields . I might do it dynamicly in future , know I need to a way to get result .